# How to transform 1 column argument and 1 values ​argument in a dataframe in scala?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I'm having difficulty creating the dataframe from an arg of column names and an arg with scala values.

It doesn't recognize spark.createDataFrame(dataClient).toDF(columns. _*)

```
val dataClient = args(0).split(",").map(_.trim)
val column = args(1).split(",").map(_.trim)

val dataClient = Seq(dataClient)
val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(dataClient).toDF(columns. _*)
```

Can I do it another way without needing a lib?

Remembering that I can't use the cloud, so import services are very limited.

A way to transform a column argument and another value argument into a dataframe

Comment: Did you write `columns. _*` or is that a typo?

Comment: Also, please clarify the types of all your values and what you mean by "it doesn't recognize": do you have a compilation error? If so, add the complete error message to your post.

Comment: @GaëlJ The error that occurred when building was:

Overloaded mathod createDataFrame with alternatives:

[A <:Product](dataClient: Seq[A](implicit evidence$3: reflect.runtime.universe.TYpeTag[A]): org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame <and> [A <:Product](rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[A]) implicit evidence$2 : reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A]): org.apache.spark.sql.Dataframe cannot be applied to (Seq[Array[String]]) val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(dataClient).toDF(columns._*)

Comment: It gives an error in this part here: val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(dataClient).toDF(columns._*)

Comment: spark.createDataFrame <- it does not recognize this function

Comment: Please edit your initial post with these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Gaël J's comment did you mean to use the "." with columns.** , the fact you c+p'd it would seem so.  The syntax is :** not ._*.

Also:

```scala
val dataClient = args(0).split(",").map(_.trim)
val column = args(1).split(",").map(_.trim)

val dataClient = Seq(dataClient)
val df: DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(dataClient).toDF(columns. _*)
```

line 1 declares dataClient as an Array[String], line 3 tries to redeclare dataClient as a Seq[Array[String]] with a single entry.  You declare column and then use column"s".

Finally createDataFrame would already create a DataFrame, so toDF doesn't make sense here.

It's not clear what you are trying to do but this code, even after those corrections but I'd assume it's this:

```scala
import spark.implicits._
val args = Seq("a,b,c,d","colname")

val dataClient = args(0).split(",").map(_.trim).toSeq
val column = args(1).trim

val df: DataFrame = dataClient.toDF(column)
df.show()
```

yielding:

```
+-------+
|colname|
+-------+
|      a|
|      b|
|      c|
|      d|
+-------+
```

The "import spark.implicits._" brings into scope all the implicit machinery needed to call DF and ".toSeq" allows that machinery to see a Seq[String] rather than an Array[String] to toDF can work.

*IF* you are trying to get multiple columns through it's not so straightforward as each "row" would be treated as an array if you use something like this:

```
import spark.implicits._
val args = Seq("a,b, c, d | e,f ,g, h ","col1, col2, col3 , col4")

val dataClient = args(0).split("\\|").map(_.trim).map(_.split(",").map(_.trim) ).toSeq
val columns = args(1).split(",").map(_.trim)

val df: DataFrame = dataClient.toDF(columns :_ *)
df.show()
```

which yields:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The number of columns doesn't match.
Old column names (1): value
New column names (4): col1, col2, col3, col4

    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
```

To make this work it would require making rows directly:

```scala
val args = Seq("a,b, c, d | e,f ,g, h ","col1, col2, col3 , col4")

val columns = args(1).split(",").map(_.trim)
val schema = StructType(columns.map(c => StructField(c, StringType)))

val dataClient = args(0).split("\\|").map(_.trim).map{ raw =>
  val rawSeq =
    raw.split(",").map(_.trim)
  new GenericRowWithSchema(rawSeq.asInstanceOf[ Array[Any] ], schema) : Row
}.toSeq

implicit val rowEnc = RowEncoder(schema)

val df = spark.createDataset(dataClient)
df.show()
```

resulting in:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|
+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|   d|
|   e|   f|   g|   h|
+----+----+----+----+
```

but this has a few things you should avoid in it:

```scala
new GenericRowWithSchema(rawSeq.asInstanceOf[ Array[Any] ], schema) : Row
```

whilst not being "internal" to Spark it's definitely not intended for you to use Spark like this.

If this is a learning experience I'd suggest making a csv file and reading that instead of trying to construct a dataframe like this, if not then I'd recommend you use a file exchange like parquet which includes the schema and doesn't come with parsing concerns like actually wanting a "," in your field (or | or whatever else you try to use as a separator).  If it really must be text then look at json which would also allow some structures to be passed in (although not map's with non-string keys).